# How to add phone no, email, website etc to existing contact

Tags: android

I am developing an application where, I have to add phone no, email, website, address etc. to my existing contact on a click of a button.

the function on the click of the button goes here

```
private void updateContact(String name) 
   {
Log.d(TAG, "in updatecontact()");
Log.d(TAG,"Contact name to be updated = "+name);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
String[] params = new String[] {name,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
        String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)};

Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, params, null);

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

if ( (phoneCur == null)  ) {
    add_new_contact();
} else {
    // Phone no
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, Tel)
            .build());
    // Email
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, Email)
            .build());
    // Website
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.DATA, Url)
            .build());
    //Organization
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA, Org)
            .build());
}

phoneCur.close();

try {
    cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

I am unable to update my contact.

Comment: It's nice to know that you're developing an application. Hope it goes well for you. BTW, why did you post this? It's not exactly a question, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am assuming that you do not know how to do that, and that is your question.

this may help

```
ContentResolver cResolver = context.getContentResolver();
public void AddToContact()
{
    insertContentValues(cResolver, Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, getPhoneCV(phone));
}

public ContentValues getPhoneCV(RowData data) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        String PhoneNumber = "055434553";
        cv.put(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER,PhoneNumber );
        return cv;
    }

private Uri insertContentValues(ContentResolver cResolver, Uri uri, ContentValues cv) {
        if (cv != null) {
          return cResolver.insert(uri, cv);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: On, what basis you have post this answer ???

Comment: i dont get it? what is the problem with the answer?

Comment: can you tell me what is the question over there ?

Comment: can you read the title of the Question!!!!

Comment: Guys I just need to update my existing contact on a click of a button. I have edited my question. You can check it.